# 3 input logic gate

Tags: logic-gates, input, homework, circuits, truth-table

I really need help because I need to come up with a circuit with 3 inputs (input A, input B and input C) and a truth table where in every case except for when input A and input C are 1 the output is 1. So basically if input A and input C are both 1, the output is 0. In all the other cases, the output is 1. 
I'm also wondering if that's even possible to make.

*Table 1. Truth table for OP to edit.*

```
A  B  C   Out
-------------
0  0  0   1
1  0  0   1
0  1  0   1
1  0  1   0
0  1  1   1
1  1  0   1
0  0  1   1
1  1  1   1
```

Comment: If the output doesn't depend on input `B`, you only need a two input logic gate. You can just have the `B` input connected to nothing inside your circuit.

Comment: Try starting with the truth table first. Once you have a fully filled out truth table, the circuit may be easier to think about.

Comment: @Maria: I've started the truth table for you. Hit the edit link below your question and complete it, filling in the output column.

Comment: I have added the homework tag to help potential folks trying to answer avoid giving away the complete solution.

Comment: @ThePhoton I wish I could do that but there is a certain rule where every input has to be connected.

Comment: Yes it's possible.

Comment: A & C into a NAND, with  that output into an OR with B.

Comment: @johnny_boy thank you for the advice, but the truth table doesn't seem to help me much. When trying to draw a circuit (using logic gates), it gets super complicated.

Comment: Truth table is missing a couple: 000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111.  3 & 6 are missing.

Comment: Take a look at Karnaugh maps make sure include 8 possible inputs. If don't care you can mark these with an X. Then tell us your thoughts. Nobody here will do your homework but we will help once we have seen your efforts.

Comment: "*... but there is a certain rule where every input has to be connected.*" That is not stated in your question. Where does that rule come from? It should be now clear from your table that there is one unique condition that you need to check for and set the output to '0'. All others give a '1'. Can you solve it?

Comment: @CrossRoads yeah, I see. Still, thank you for the help.

Comment: @Transistor the program I'm doing is really complex and has many implications and rules which I didn't write about because that's irrelevant to everyone here. But I see your point.

Comment: 101 and 111 both result in output = 0? B = don't care? Then 2 input NAND.  I don't understand where you are having difficulty.

Comment: OK, so write out the boolean equation for that one case and then use the schematic button on the editor toolbar to draw the schematic. All the logic symbols you require are built in. Hit Save and Insert when done.

Comment: @CrossRoads no, only 101 output = 0.

Comment: Ok, so 2-input NAND followed by 2-input OR to bring in B.  OR can go low when A&C are High and B is Low.

Comment: @CrossRoads ok, i'll have a look at it myself because i feel like there's some misunderstanding. thank you for your help.

Comment: @Maria Lim, Your description and the truth table do not match (your description says B is "don't care", your truth table says something different). It's impossible to answer unless you remove the conflicting information from your question. You should edit the question for this. Comments are just fleeting / temporary and could be removed in the future.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAoOI1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVzB0Q.png)</sup>

```
NAND

A  C  Out
0  0  1
0  1  1
1  0  1
1  1  0

OR 
A/C  B  Out
0    0  0    So A = C = 1, B = 0, Output = 0
0    1  1
1    0  1
1    1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems simple. Just a 3 input NAND gate with the B input inverted.

Why does this work? Because it means that in any case except for that 1 0 1 case, it will be on.

Simulatorio: https://simulator.io/board/KeuHkS0cwt/1